# How to start/stop a windows service from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, windows-services

I have following three user roles in my application.

1. SuperAdmin
2. Admin
3. User

I want to start/stop a service only for the user who have SuperAdmin user role.

The need of the application is to start/stop a Service (or any other service running what you want to start/stop) from an ASP.NET web application.

Comment: What is this solution that you mention ? For me one easy way is to call the `net start MSSQLSERVER` and `net stop MSSQLSERVER` from code behind, for the users that you specify and must have been logged on your pages. Of course my advice is to not do it and find some other way to deal with your issues... sql server must not stop at all.

Comment: You'd be better off issuing a `SHUTDOWN` command to SQL Server itself to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have did in the above scenario where I have to Start Stop my Monitoring Server service from Asp.Net web application using c#.

Add the `System.ServiceProcess` for default `Start();` `Stop();` `Refresh();` functions

#### Code Behind

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

private readonly ServiceController _monitoringServer = new ServiceController("MONITORING$SERVER");

// on login screen, I just saved the userRole of a Loggedin user in Session["userRole"]

// On pageload, refresh the sql service and gets its current status.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _monitoringServer.Refresh();
    GetServiceCurrentStatus();

    // if userRole of loggedIn user is SuperAdmin, then it will make the buttons visible to the user
    // else it will hide the buttons and show only status of SQL SERVER to admin user and standard/limited user
    if(Session["userRole"] == "SuperAdmin"){
        this.btnStartServer.Visible = true;
        this.btnStopServer.Visible = true;
    }
    else{
        this.btnStartServer.Visible = false;
        this.btnStopServer.Visible = false;
    }
    // You can further login to show hide Start Stop buttons
}

// Start Server Function
protected void btnStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _monitoringServer.Refresh();

    if (_monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
    {
        _monitoringServer.Start();
        _monitoringServer.Refresh();
    }
    GetServiceCurrentStatus();
}

// Stop Server Function
protected void btnStopServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _monitoringServer.Refresh();
    if (_monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        _monitoringServer.Stop();
        _monitoringServer.Refresh();
    }
    GetServiceCurrentStatus();
}

// Get Current Status of SQL Service Function
private void GetServiceCurrentStatus()
{
    try
    {
        _monitoringServer.Refresh();

        if (_monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            this.txtServerStatus.Text = "Monitoring Server: Running";
        else if (_monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            this.txtServerStatus.Text = "Monitoring Server: Stopped";
        else if (_monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
                this.txtServerStatus.Text = "Monitoring Server: Starting...";
        else if (_monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
            this.txtServerStatus.Text = "Monitoring Server: Stopping...";
        else if (_monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Paused || _monitoringServer.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.PausePending)
            this.txtServerStatus.Text = "Monitoring Server: Pause";
        else
            this.txtServerStatus.Text = "Monitoring Server: Processing";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.txtServerStatus.Text = "Monitoring Server: Not Installed";
    }
}

// Timer Function
protected void ServerTimer_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _monitoringServer.Refresh();
}
```

#### Client Side

```
// On client side, I just used a timer and sets its interval to 2 seconds (2000ms)
// after every 2 seconds it executes the ServerTimer_OnTick function which refreshes the status
<asp:Timer ID="ServerTimer" runat="server" Interval="2000" OnTick="ServerTimer_OnTick"></asp:Timer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Service Controll Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start/stop the service, not `SHUTDOWN` T-SQL verb. The SCM knows about service dependencies and will properly shutdown dependent services like SQL Agent. Besides, only the SCM can *start* the service. The managed API of the SCM is the [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. That takes care of the problem of starting/stopping the service(s).

Now, about impersonation. Why do care? Determining if a user is "superadmin" (whatever that means) or not is your app specific logic. Authenticate and authorize in your ASP.Net logic, then grant the app pool principal the required privilege to start and stop services. See [Service Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note how Local authenticated users have all the necessary privileges to connect to SCM and start/stop services.

If you do choose to impersonate, then it falls to the impersonated context to have the necessary privileges. There is no such concept as 'super admin' in Windows, you will impersonate an Active Directory account and that account will have or not have permissions to connect to SCM and start/stop services.